# Arrays showing vertically instead of horizontally

Tags: java, arrays

I am sort of new to programming and I am working on a school assignments on arrays

I am suppose to write a program that stores statistics using arrays.

```
import java.io.*;
public class HockeyLeague {
static final int Rows = 7;
static final int Cols = 8;
static double HockeyChart [][] = new double[Rows][Cols];
static HockeyLeague HL = new HockeyLeague();
static BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
public static void main(String args[])throws IOException {
    while(true){
        System.out.println("Welcome to the NHL statistic program");
        System.out.println("Would you like to proceed to the program? <y for yes, n for no>");
        final String menuDecision = br.readLine();
        if (menuDecision.equals("n")) {
            System.out.println("Goodbye");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        if (menuDecision.equals("y")) {
            while(true) {
            System.out.println("The 8 teams are Toronto Maple Leafs, Montreal Canadiens, Ottawa Senators, Detroit Red Wings, Boston Bruins,"+
            " Chicago Blackhawks, New York Islanders, and Pitsburg Penguins");
            System.out.println("To input statistics for Toronto, enter '0' ");
            System.out.println("To input statistics for Montreal, enter '1' ");
            System.out.println("To input statistics for Ottawa, enter '2' ");
            System.out.println("To input statistics for Detroit, enter '3' ");
            System.out.println("To input statistics for Boston, enter '4' ");
            System.out.println("To input statistics for Chicago, enter '5' ");
            System.out.println("To input statistics for New York, enter '6' ");
            System.out.println("To input statistics for Pitsburg, enter '7' ");
            int numString = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

            Info (numString);

           }
       }
    }       
}

public static double[][] Info(int teamInput)throws IOException{
    System.out.println("Enter the amount of games played");
    int games = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    HockeyChart [0+teamInput][1] = games;
    System.out.println("Enter the amount of wins");
    int wins = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    HockeyChart [0+teamInput][2] = wins;
    System.out.println("Enter the amount of ties");
    int ties = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    HockeyChart [0+teamInput][3] = ties;
    System.out.println("Enter the amount of losses");
    int losses = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    HockeyChart [0+teamInput][4] = losses;
    System.out.println("Enter the amount of goals scored");
    int goals = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    HockeyChart [0+teamInput][5] = goals;
    for (int i = 0; i < Rows; i ++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < Cols;j ++) {
            System.out.println(HockeyChart[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("  ");
    }
    return HockeyChart;
 }  
}
```

This is the program I came up with. I dont understand why I get an output that is a long vertical row of numbers instead of row of numbers side by side.

Any help would be appreciated! thanks

Comment: Aside from anything else, I'd strongly recommend learning about Java naming conventions and starting to follow them - variables and methods should start with a lower-case letter, and your `Info` method should probably be something more like `enterTeamInfo`. I'd strongly suggest getting into the habit of making all fields private, too.

Answer (score 0):

In your Info method, while iterating over arrays, you are using System.out.println(), instead of that you will need to use System.out.print() method.

```
for (int i = 0; i < Rows; i ++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < Cols;j ++) {
        System.out.print(HockeyChart[i][j] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Second println statement will help you to move to next line after one row is printed.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your loop:

```
for (int j = 0; j < Cols;j ++) {
    System.out.println(HockeyChart[i][j] + " ");
}
```

`println` is short for Print Line - it prints the given string, and then moves on to the next line. If you want to print all the contents of the array in a single line, you could use `System.out.print` instead:

```
for (int j = 0; j < Cols;j ++) {
    System.out.print(HockeyChart[i][j] + " ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `System.out.println` which means print in new line.

You can use `System.out.print` for same line i.e horizontal row.

Code will be like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < Rows; i ++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < Cols;j ++) {
        System.out.print(HockeyChart[i][j] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println("  ");
}
return HockeyChart;
```